# calling an api multiple times using WorkManager in android

Tags: android, kotlin, background-process, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

**I want to call an api multiple times using WorkManager.**

where **idsArrayList** is a list of ids.
I send each id in the api as Path to get response and similarly for other ids.
I want the workManager to return success after it has called api for all ids.

But the problem is WorkManager only returns SUCCESS for one id from the list. This is the first time I'm using WorkManager and I tried starting work manager for every id too by iterating over idsList one by one and making instance of workManger for every id in the for loop. But I thought sending the idsList as data in the workmanager and then itering over ids from inside doWork() would be better, but it's not working like I want and I don't understand why. Here's my code:

```
    class MyWorkManager(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters):
    Worker(appContext, workerParams) {

    private lateinit var callGrabShifts: Call<ConfirmStatus>

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val idsList = inputData.getStringArray("IDS_LIST")
        val idsArrayList = idsList?.toCollection(ArrayList())
        var response = ""
        if (idsArrayList != null) {
            try {
      
                response = callConfirmShiftApi(idsArrayList)
                if (response.contains("CONFIRM")) {
                 
                    return Result.success()
                } 
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                return Result.failure()
            }
        }

        return Result.retry()
    }

    private fun callConfirmShiftApi(idsArrayList: ArrayList<String>): String {
        var response = ""
        for ((index, id) in idsArrayList.withIndex()) {
         
            response = callApiForId(id)
           
            if(index == idsArrayList.lastIndex) {
                response = "CONFIRM"
            }
        }
        return response
    }

    private fun callApiForId(id: String): String {
        var shiftGrabStatus = ""
      
        callGrabShifts = BaseApp.apiInterface.confirmGrabAllShifts(BaseApp.userId, id)
        callGrabShifts.enqueue(object : Callback<ConfirmStatus> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ConfirmStatus>, response: Response<ConfirmStatus>) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    shiftGrabStatus = response.body()!!.status
                    if (shiftGrabStatus != null) {
                        if (shiftGrabStatus.contains("CONFIRM")) {
                            
                            val shiftNumber = ++BaseApp.noOfShiftsGrabbed
                            
                            sendNotification(applicationContext)
                            shiftGrabStatus = "CONFIRM"
                            return
                        } else {
                            shiftGrabStatus = "NOT CONFIRM"
                            return
                        }
                    } else {
                        shiftGrabStatus = "NULL"
                        return
                    }
                } else {
                    shiftGrabStatus = "NULL"
                    return
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ConfirmStatus>, t: Throwable) {
               
                shiftGrabStatus = "FAILURE"
                return
            }
        })
        return shiftGrabStatus
    }    
}
```

And this is the code where I'm starting the WorkManager:

```
private fun confirmShiftApi(availableShiftsIdList: ArrayList<String>) {
        
        val data = Data.Builder()
        data.putStringArray("IDS_LIST", availableShiftsIdList.toArray(arrayOfNulls<String>(availableShiftsIdList.size)))

        val oneTimeWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorkManager>().setInputData(data.build())
            .build()
        WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).enqueue(oneTimeWorkRequest)
      
        WorkManager.getInstance(this).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(oneTimeWorkRequest.id)
            .observe(this, Observer { workInfo: WorkInfo? ->
                if (workInfo != null && workInfo.state.isFinished) {
                    val progress = workInfo.progress           
                }
                Log.d("TESTING", "(MainActivity) : observing work manager - workInfo?.state - ${workInfo?.state}")
            })
    }
```

Any suggestions what I might be doing wrong or any other alternative to perform the same? I chose workmanager basicaly to perform this task even when app is closed and for learning purposes as I haven't used WorkManager before. But would switch to other options if this doesn't work.

Comment: I think you need repository man, the only way I solve this by treating Worker just like an activity/fragment. the worker didn't know anything about the logic, their purpose is just calling a function inside repository to do some async task with coroutine IO thread.

Comment: The actual issue was from backend, the api was returning failure when it was called repeatedly. Though with workmanager, it didn't make much difference even by adding delay but with Service, It worked way better with same added delay between api calls(400ms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following things:

1. removed the 'var response line in every method that I'm using to set the response, though I added it temporarily just for debugging earlier but it was causing an issue.
2. I removed the check for "CONFIRM" in doWork() method and just made the api calls, removed the extra return lines.
3. I tried adding manual delay in between api calls for each id.
4. I removed the code where I'm sending the ids data from my activity before calling workmanager and made the api call to fetch those ids inside workmanager and added more delay in between those calls to that keep running in background to check for data one round completes(to call api for all ids that were fetched earlier, it had to call api again to check for more ids on repeat)
5. I removed the extra api calls from onRestart() and from other conditons that were required to call api again.
6. I tested only one round of api calls for all ids with delay and removed the repeated call part just to test first. Didn't work.

None of the above worked, it just removed extra lines of code.

This is my final code that is tested and It cleared my doubt. Though it **didn't fix** this issue as the problem was because of backend server and Apis were returning failure in onResponse callback for most ids(when calls are made repeatedly using a for loop for each id) except first id and randomly last id from the list sometimes(with delay) for the rest of the ids it didn't return CONFIRM status message from api using Workmanager. Adding delay didn't make much difference.

**Here's my Workmanager code:**

```
    class MyWorkManager(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters):
        Worker(appContext, workerParams) {
    
        private lateinit var callGrabShifts: Call<ConfirmStatus>
    
        override fun doWork(): Result {
            val idsList = inputData.getStringArray("IDS_LIST")
            val idsArrayList = idsList?.toCollection(ArrayList())
            if (idsArrayList != null) {
                try {
                    response = callConfirmShiftApi(idsArrayList)
                    if (response.contains("CONFIRM")) {
                        return Result.success()
                    } 
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    return Result.failure()
                }
            }
            return Result.success()
        }
    
        private fun callConfirmShiftApi(idsArrayList: ArrayList<String>): String {
            for ((index, id) in idsArrayList.withIndex()) {
                response = callApiForId(id)
                Thread.sleep(800)
                if(index == idsArrayList.lastIndex) {
                    response = "CONFIRM"
                }
            }
            return response
        }
    
        private fun callApiForId(id: String): String {
callGrabShifts = BaseApp.apiInterface.confirmGrabAllShifts(BaseApp.userId, id)
 callGrabShifts.enqueue(object : Callback<ConfirmStatus> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<ConfirmStatus>, response: Response<ConfirmStatus>) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        shiftGrabStatus = response.body()!!.status
                        if (shiftGrabStatus != null) {
                            if (shiftGrabStatus.contains("CONFIRM")) {
                                return
                            } else {
                                return
                            }
                        } else {
                            return
                        }
                    } else {
                        return
                    }
                }
    
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ConfirmStatus>, t: Throwable) {
                    return
                }
            })
    
            return shiftGrabStatus
        }
```

Eventually this problem(when an individual call is made for an id, it always returns success but when i call the api for every id using a loop, it only returns success for first call and failure for others) was solved using Service, it didn't have a complete success rate from apis either, but for 6/11 ids the api returned success(400ms delay between each api call), so it served the purpose for now.